# load file from queue in tensorflow

Tags: python, csv, numpy, tensorflow, queue

I am trying to create an input pipeline in tensorflow that will load data from different csv files and pass the data to a RNN.

What i want to do is use a queue to fetch csv filenames and then use the filename with numpy and load data. What i have done so far is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import numpy as np

files = glob.glob("*.csv")

fqueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
x = fqueue.dequeue()
csv = np.genfromtxt(x, delimiter=",")
x_data = csv[:,0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for i in range(30):
         print sess.run([x_data])
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

And i am getting this error on `genfromtxt`:

```
TypeError: fname must be a string, filehandle, list of strings, or generator. Got <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> instead.
```

I am aware of TextLineReader that can read lines from csv files, but the way the csv files are structured, i need to read it per column, not per row, so i am trying to use numpy for this.

Is there a way either with Tensorflow or using my method with numpy to read these csv files per column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this in a proper way.
It seems that because you get values when you actually start your session, numpy will complain. I was able to solve the problem by replacing:

```
csv = np.genfromtxt(x, delimiter=",")
```

with a function:

```
def get_np_array(x):
    return np.genfromtxt(x, delimiter=",", dtype=np.float32)
```

then using:

```
csv = tf.py_func(get_np_array, [x], tf.float32)
```

But i didnt use this solution because i read that using py_func is not very efficient.
What i ended up doing was to convert my csv files to tfrecords, and have them in  the correct format and shape. I do need to convert the csv files to tfrecords every time i have more data but it works ok.